# How can I pass properties to child component when using it within the router tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I am developing a web application that needs to pass information from the App component to other child components. I want to pass properties from the App component to the Questionnaire component. I want to pass the properties when a callback from the QuestionForm component is triggered. I am unable to pass data as props. When I read the props from within the questionnaire component it is showing up as null. Can someone please help? This is the render function of the App component which I have defined as a class.:

**App.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Login from "./Login";
import useToken from './useToken';
import Console from "./Console";
import Questionnaire from "./Questionnaire";
import QuestionForm from './QuestionForm';
import SummaryGrid from './SummaryGrid';
import "./App.css";
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        token: null,
        examinerName: "",
        examCodes: [],
        examNames: [],
        questionCount: [],
        examCodeSelection: false,
        submitDate: null,
        submitTime: null
    };

    this.saveToken = this.saveToken.bind(this);
    this.getToken = this.getToken.bind(this);
    this.routePage = this.routePage.bind(this);
    this.handleEntryComplete = this.handleEntryComplete.bind(this);
    this.handleExamCodes = this.handleExamCodes.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmission = this.handleSubmission.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({token: this.getToken()})
    this.routePage();
  }

  routePage = () => {
    if (this.state.currentView === 'ENTRY')
    {
      window.location.href = "/";
    }
    else if (this.state.currentView === 'QUESTIONNAIRE')
    {
      window.location.href = "/questionnaire";
    }
    else if (this.state.currentView === 'SUMMARY')
    {
      window.location.href = "/summary";
    }
  }

  handleExamCodes = (name,codes,exams,counts) => {
    this.setState({examinerName: name, examCodes: codes, examNames: exams, questionCount: counts});
  }

  handleEntryComplete = (code) => {
    this.setState({currentView: 'QUESTIONNAIRE'});
    this.setState({examCodeSelection: true},this.routePage);
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.token) {
      return (<div>
              <Login setToken={this.saveToken} setExamCodes={this.handleExamCodes}/>
              </div>)
    }
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
      <div className="wrapper">
      <Router>
        <Console getSubmitTime={this.handleSubmission}/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<QuestionForm examCodeList={this.state.examCodes} examNameList={this.state.examNames} questionCountList={this.state.questionCount} passExamCode={this.handleEntryComplete}/>}/>
          <Route path="/questionnaire" element={<Questionnaire examiner={this.state.examinerName} examCode={this.state.examCodeSelection}/>}/>
          <Route path="/summary" element={<Summary/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see no `data` prop, so I'm guessing that is why it's undefined/null in `Questionnaire`. You are already passing other props to these routed components, so what exactly is the issue? Please also try to include all relevant code in your question as part of a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "examiner" and "examCode" are the properties that I want to pass to the Questionnaire component. It is for these props that I am getting a null value. @DrewReese

Comment: I guess `this.state.examinerName` and `this.state.examCodeSelection` are both null then. We need more context and a more complete view of this `App` component to likely provide any further help. We can't debug what we can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you use routing like this you will always get props null because on every route you are refreshing the page so state get refreshed. Please remove your routePage method this is not the way of routing in React.
[See React Router Documentation](https://reactrouter.com/) you will get an idea how to do Routing on React